# Converting from word document to native google doc

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

So I have some 2000 word documents I can generate with c#, however, I need them uploaded to google docs, in the native google docs format.

I looked at [This guide](https://ctrlq.org/code/20102-convert-office-files-to-google-docs) to try to convert them, however, the code fails on the second to last line.

(My code below)

```
function myFunction() {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("test").next();
  var contents = folder.getFiles();
  while (contents.hasNext()){
    var file = contents.next();
    var fileName = file.getName();
    var officeFile = DriveApp.getFilesByName(fileName).next();
    // Use the Advanced Drive API to upload the Excel file to Drive
    // convert = true will convert the file to the corresponding Google Docs format
    var uploadFile = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(
      "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=media&convert=true", 
      {
        method: "POST",
        contentType: officeFile.getMimeType(),
        payload: officeFile.getBlob().getBytes(),
        headers: {
          "Authorization" : "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
        },
        muteHttpExceptions: true
      }
    ).getContentText());


    // Remove the file extension from the original file name
    var fileName2 = officeFile.getName();
    fileName2 = fileName2.substr(0, fileName2.lastIndexOf("."));


    // Update the name of the Google Sheet created from the Excel sheet
    DriveApp.getFileById(uploadFile.getID()).setName(fileName2);  // FAILS HERE

    //Logger.log(uploadFile.alternateLink);  
  }}
```

TypeError: Cannot find function getID in object [object Object]. (line 33, file "Code")

I understand what kind of error this is, however, I do not necessarily know how to solve it.

Comment: In the guide you quoted, the Id is obtained as `uploadFile.id` -- it's a property of the object returned by the upload API.

Comment: @zaq I tried that, and was getting the same error. I will try again.

Comment: Try logging the object uploadFile so you know for sure what properties it has. `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(uploadFile))`, for example.

Comment: @zaq Digging through the log, I am returned (HTTP?) 400, "invalid mime type provided"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any UrlFetchApp manipulations. The [Advanced Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive) provides conversion as a part of `copy` method. Takes two lines of code:

```
  var fileId = 'ID_of_Word_file';
  Drive.Files.copy({}, fileId, {'convert': true});
```

You will need to enable this service in the scropt menu: see Resources > Advanced Services.

If iterating through a folder, get each file from file iterator with `.next()` and use `getId()` to get its id; the proceed as above.

The empty object in the first argument can be used to name the new file: e.g., it could be `{'title': 'Name of new file'}`

Comment: It even copies the file to the same directory! Thank you!

Comment: @user6655984 -- Thanks -- very useful. However, to make this work now (Feb 2024), you _need_ the first parameter of copy() to specify the title of the target google document, but also the mime type, thus -- {'title' : 'new file name', 'mimeType'  :  'application/vnd.google-apps.document'}. Otherwise, the statement executes without throwing an error, but the target file does not get created.